# Excluding root from prt_jobs

Tags: ruby, bash, root, printers

I'm making a program that will run through a printer server and cancel jobs that are hung. As of right now it outputs everything, and what I want to do is exclude `root`:

Output:

```
credjet-898837          cdd            5312512   Wed 14 Oct 2015 03:42:32 PM CDT
credjet-898839          cdd            1998848   Wed 14 Oct 2015 03:45:32 PM CDT
credjet-940485          cdd            1206272   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:10:30 PM CST
credjet-940499          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:21:42 PM CST
credjet-940505          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:29:26 PM CST
credjet-940509          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:38:24 PM CST
credjet-940514          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:00:02 PM CST
credjet-940515          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:00:17 PM CST
credjet-940525          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:10:46 PM CST
credjet-940526          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:11:01 PM CST
credjet-940528          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:12:44 PM CST
credjet-940602          cdd            2382848   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:26:09 PM CST
devljet-931153          siv            1798144   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:38:30 PM CST
devljet-931157          siv            3278848   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:47:18 PM CST
devljet-931158          siv            1538048   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:47:18 PM CST
laser11-917719          root             78848   Wed 18 Nov 2015 09:56:47 PM CST
laser11-918257          root             78848   Thu 19 Nov 2015 09:45:23 PM CST
laser11-918262          root             79872   Thu 19 Nov 2015 09:49:30 PM CST
laser11-918263          root             78848   Thu 19 Nov 2015 09:53:45 PM CST
```

Expected Output:

```
credjet-898837          cdd            5312512   Wed 14 Oct 2015 03:42:32 PM CDT
credjet-898839          cdd            1998848   Wed 14 Oct 2015 03:45:32 PM CDT
credjet-940485          cdd            1206272   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:10:30 PM CST
credjet-940499          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:21:42 PM CST
credjet-940505          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:29:26 PM CST
credjet-940509          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 01:38:24 PM CST
credjet-940514          cdd             342016   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:00:02 PM CST
credjet-940515          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:00:17 PM CST
credjet-940525          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:10:46 PM CST
credjet-940526          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:11:01 PM CST
credjet-940528          cdd            2387968   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:12:44 PM CST
credjet-940602          cdd            2382848   Mon 04 Jan 2016 02:26:09 PM CST
devljet-931153          siv            1798144   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:38:30 PM CST
devljet-931157          siv            3278848   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:47:18 PM CST
devljet-931158          siv            1538048   Fri 18 Dec 2015 02:47:18 PM CST 
#<= No more root
```

Is there a way that I can output the same information, but exclude the root jobs?

---

Source:

```
#!/local/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'etc'        

class PrintJobs

  HOST = '<server here>' #<= Left blank for security 
  USERNAME = Etc.getlogin
  PASSWORD = nil

  def scan_for_jobs
    check_jobs = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USERNAME, :password => PASSWORD) do |ssh|
      cmd = "prt_jobs"
      res = ssh.exec!(cmd)
      puts res
    end
  end
end

test = PrintJobs.new
test.scan_for_jobs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of unwanted lines by using below code:

```
  res = ssh.exec!(cmd)
  res = res.split("\n").reject {|line| line.match(/\s+root\s+/)}.join("\n")
  puts res
```

The result of [`exec!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net/SSH/Connection/Session#exec%21-instance_method) is one string containing the output of command issued over ssh.  Hence, we need to split it by newline and iterate over the array to reject the lines containing `root` and re-join the array using new line.